# Hierarchical Task Network Planner in Python

Tags: java, python, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, planning

Is anyone aware of a [hierarchical task network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_task_network) planner implemented in Python or Java? I've found a few [open source systems](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shop/), but they're all seemingly [dead projects](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/~oplan/release/index.html) and [haven't been maintained](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/plus/umcp/manual/) in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about JSHOP2?

Comment: How about it? Do you have experience with it?

Comment: I used it in the past. I took a class with one of the authors. The software was well written and it seemed well maintained. However, this was in the second half of 2005.

Comment: I also found JSHOP2-rt, which appears to be a slightly more recent fork that supports real-time planning.